# FileOutputStream throws java.io.FileNotFoundException for relative path

Tags: java

When using a relative path to access images in my application:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/images/imag.jpg");
```

I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException, but if I provide the whole path its works

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
    "C:/Users/seema/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SpiceCareers/web/images/imag.jpg");
```

I need to use relative paths in my project, how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: what is your current working directory?

Comment: the 'whole thing' is absolute path. What you are looking for is relative path and will be calculated from your working dir.

Comment: Don't use relative paths, instead load your images via [resource streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 3):

I think you should remove the first slash in the path since it tries to locate it in the root directory. Instead it should be :

```
new FileOutputStream("images/imag.jpg");
```